# Method not found: 'Asp.Versioning.ApiVersion Asp.Versioning.IApiVersionParser.Parse(System.String)'

Tags: version

I use this code to add version on .net freamwork 4.6.2:

Asp.Versioning.WebApi : 7.0.0
Asp.Versioning.WebApi.ApiExplorer : 7.0.0

config:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/v{apiVersion}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            config.AddApiVersioning(options =>
                {
                    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
                    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                    options.Conventions.Add(new VersionByNamespaceConvention());
                    options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
                    options.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(
                        new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader(),
                        new HeaderApiVersionReader("x-api-version"),
                        new MediaTypeApiVersionReader("x-api-version"));
                }
            );
SwaggerConfig.Register(config);
```

controller

```
[HandleError]
    [ApiVersion("1")]
    [System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class BaseController : ApiController
    {
}
```

```
[ApiVersion("1")]
public class CustomerController : BaseController
{
}
```

but when call api method like this, I get error:

http://localhost:63593/api/v1/Customer/GetErrors?userCode=1

```
<Error ml-update="aware" ml-stage="preload" ml-view="top">
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>Method not found: 'Asp.Versioning.ApiVersion Asp.Versioning.IApiVersionParser.Parse(System.String)'.</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.MissingMethodException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace> at Asp.Versioning.ApiVersionRequestProperties.get_RequestedApiVersion() at Asp.Versioning.Dispatcher.ControllerSelectionContext.get_RequestedVersion() at Asp.Versioning.Dispatcher.DirectRouteControllerSelector.SelectController(ControllerSelectionContext context) at Asp.Versioning.Dispatcher.ApiVersionControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()</StackTrace>
</Error>
```